# What GUI toolkit uses the windows class names 'wcl_manager1' or 'wcl_internal_window_class'?

Tags: windows, user-interface, toolkit

I have an application and would like to know what GUI toolkit was used to implement it. The list of DLLs which it uses at runtime wasn't very enlightening, I didn't recognize anything. Tools like Spy++ or UISpy show that the windows have class names like `wcl_manager1` (apparently toplevel windows) or `wcl_internal_window_class` (for anything else). Most of the controls (line edits, check boxes, buttons) don't even have a native window, i.e. no `HWND` associated.

Does anybody know what GUI toolkit this might be?

Comment: probably some internal kit like directUI

Answer (score -1):

Look up ProcessId property and you'll figure it out.
In my case it was CiscoJabber.exe with "20200" window name.

Comment: I already know what process created the windows (as I wrote, I already enumerated its DLLs). I would like to know the name of the GUI toolkit used by the application.